# What does "delete k ::ffff:192.168.0.1_51879" in node terminal mean?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I have this strange log in my node terminal:

```
delete k ::ffff:192.168.0.1_51879
```

I did not log this deliberately. Did node log this on its own?

If so, does it have something to do with a killed process (socket)? What does it mean?

Comment: Probably. `::ffff` and `192.168.0.1` look like local IP addresses. Based on that, `51879` is likely the port.

Comment: Sounds right. But why is it in my terminal?

Comment: @Fusscreme Because your app logs it. Its impossible to say why this gets printed without more details what kind of app this is or what dependencies you use...